# What, exactly, is the Fermi Constant? What is its value? And what is the difference between $G_f$ and $G_f^0$?

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, weak-interaction, electroweak

There is no Wikipedia page for Fermi's Constant, and the page they DO have is confusing.

From [Fermi's Interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction):

[image]

How can $G_f^0$ not be equal to $G_f$?
What is the difference?

And when they give the approximate value in Joules, they mean $10^{-14}$, right, not $10^{14}$? Even then, the values given in Joules and GeV are not that close...

Why are the values in GeV and Joules written with a '-2' exponent after them?

EDIT: P.S.:

From the Oxford Reference, on the Fermi Constant:

https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095815800

It lists the value as, '$1.435×10^-36 joule metre^3$'.

How is that related to the other values?  Do they actually mean joules per cubic meter?  Or is the superscript 3 a misprint?  Or do they mean 'joule-meter' or 'joule-cubic meter'?

I am confused again, Mr. Cosmos Zachos....

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open-and-shut question about [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics)), the standard universal units of high energy physics, taught in the first day of class, and *never* looked back from. The units are ℏ for action, so ℏ=1 in them, *c* for speed, so *c*=1 in them, and MeV (or GeV) for energy. But, given the system, and the implicit instruction to omit all ℏs and *c*s and only reinstate them when one talks to an engineer or a chemist (*uniquely, by dimensional analysis consistency*) particle physicists use the MeV also as a unit of mass, inverse time, etc. So energy, mass, inverse time, inverse length, etc, have the same units in this system.

Wikipedia attempts to address itself to both worlds, the particle physicist's and the engineer's, without explaining the system, and ends up being a little inconsistent:
$$G_{\rm F}^0=\frac{G_{\rm F}}{(\hbar c)^3}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}\frac{g^{2}}{M_{\rm W}^{2} c^4} \\ =1.1663787(6)\times10^{-5} \; {1\over\textrm{GeV}^{2}} \approx 4.5437957\times10^{14} \; {1\over\textrm{J}^{2}}\ , $$
but
$$ 
G_{\rm F}^0\simeq \frac {\pi \alpha}{\sqrt{2}~ M_{\rm W}^2 (1- M^2_{\rm W}/M^2_{\rm Z}  )}~, 
 $$
a little further down.

The red-blooded particle physicist will use the latter expression, namely inverse-squared-mass in inverse-squared-GeVs.

- Indeed, in natural units, $G_F^0= G_F$, as ℏs and *c*s  are invisible. I see *no* good reason to include $G_F$ in the 2nd member of the top equation, or even define it, as you never use engineering/SI units in weak interaction calculations. The outcomes of these calculations are lifetimes, cross-sections, etc..., rendered dimensionally consistent at the very end by suitable insertions of powers of ℏs and *c*s.
- The value given is in inverse GeVs squared; since GeV~1.6 $\times 10^{-10}$ J, the conversion is sound. I see no point in taking the numerator downstairs, but, indeed, you may rewrite the constant as ~ 4.5/(10$^{-7}$ J)$^2$.

To sum up, I would personally avoid the meretricious laconism (WP is edited by a sedulously pedantic mob) confusing you; by just writing
$$G_{\rm F}^0 c^{-4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}\frac{g^{2}}{M_{\rm W}^{2} c^4}=1.1663787(6)\times10^{-5} \; {1\over\textrm{GeV}^{2}} \approx 4.5437957\times10^{14} \; {1\over\textrm{J}^{2}}\ , $$
admittedly weird-looking, but instantly understood by both communities.

Now, to finally answer your question, this constant (reflecting the intermediation of low-energy weak interactions, such as β decay, by virtual *W* exchange) is the "net strength" of Fermi's (1933) simple four-fermion weak interaction, the first trenchant application of QFT to physics (really!!). It was known early on, quite accurately, from the muon decay rate, to which, of course, its square is proportional, $1/\tau_\mu= \Gamma_\mu \propto G_F^2 m_\mu^5$.

---

*So... how do you redimensionalize? (Geeky)*

The basis of dimensions for the natural units  system  consists of E (energy), A (action), and V (speed), so
$$
[A]= [M L^2 T^{-1}]; \qquad [V]= [LT^{-1}]; \qquad [E]=[M L^2 T^{-2}]; \implies \\ 
[M]= [E V^{-2}]; \qquad  [L]= [E^{-1} VA];\qquad [T]=[E^{-1} A]~. 
$$
In this system, one measures A in units of ℏ, and V in units of *c*, so all physical quantities are in units of E, such as GeV.

Given one such in units of E, one merely needs to *know* the  dimensions of the quantity, in any system, a priori; and this then suffices to restore unique powers of ℏ and *c* after the natural units expression, so as to convert it to a system-independent one, like the WP one.

For example, for muon decay in natural units, as seen above,
$$
[G_F]=[E^{-2}A^xV^y],
$$
we need to the omitted powers of A and V, i.e., the powers of  ℏ and *c* to be reinstated in, e.g., an SI expression.
From basic QFT considerations outranging this discussion, we know a priori
$$
[G_F]= [M L^5 T^{-2}]~~~\implies \\
[G_F]= [E^{-2} A^3 V^3],
$$
so the muon decay determination above instantly redimensionalizes to
$$
G_F^2 \propto {\hbar^7 \over \tau_\mu m_\mu^5 c^4   }~~,
$$
e.g. cf. Griffiths (10.39).